# Combine rows and put their values in seperate column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, subquery

I want to combine two or more rows which have the same name and put their values in two separate column. The problem can be clearer with the following images:
[image]

My expected output is:

[image]

You can check the fiddle here: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/904e1/1)

What I have tried so far is with the MySQL code:

```
Select subjects, mark_score, activity 
   FROM(
      SELECT subjects,  mark_score, 
      (SELECT regd, subjects, mark_score 
       FROM exo_i WHERE entry='7' and regd='19') as activity 
       FROM exo_i WHERE regd='19' GROUP BY subjects)t
```

Comment: I'm assuming you want to display "marks" for the FA1 entry and "activity" for the SA1 activity. Do I understand the requirement correctly?

Comment: @Mureinik, Yes you are right. That's what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comment, the requirement is to display "marks" for the "FA1" entry and "activity" for the "SA1" activity. Assuming there can't be multiple rows with these values (i.e., the combination of `regd`, `subjectsa` and `activity` is unique), you could have a subquery for each of these activities, and join them:

```
SELECT a.regd, a.subjects, a.marks, b.activity
FROM   (SELECT regd, subjects, marks
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  entry = 'FA1') a
JOIN   (SELECT regd, subjects, marks AS activity
        FROM   mytable
        WHERE  entry = 'SA1') b ON a.regd = b.regd AND a.subjects = b.subjects
```